# What is the name of the line you enter commands on after hitting escape?

Tags: command-line

What is the name of the line you enter commands on after hitting escape?

E.g. When you hit escape and start typing a colon command you are typing in/on the _____ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say it's the "command line" based on http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#Command-line

Comment: I always thought people were talking about the terminal emulator and/or running shell commands in vim when they mentioned the command line. Thanks.